# R:Extracting words from one column into different columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I've been figuring this out for a couple of hours now.
Let's say I have a column with 1-4 words, separated by space:

```
aba bkak absbs
a2aj akls bios
sad
fasa lgk
.
.
.
```

I would like those words to be in separate columns, for easier further processing. SO instead those words are in one column, how do I get them to separate columns?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'V1', ' ')
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, 'V1', paste0('V', 1:4), sep= ' ', extra='drop')
```

Or using `base R`

```
read.table(text=df1$V1, sep=' ', fill=TRUE)
```

NOTE: Used the column name as 'V1' and dataset as 'df1'

Answer (score 4):

With the devel verison of `data.table` could also do

```
library(data.table) # V >= 1.9.5
setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(V1, ' ')]
#      V1   V2    V3
# 1:  aba bkak absbs
# 2: a2aj akls  bios
# 3:  sad   NA    NA
# 4: fasa  lgk    NA
```

Or with `stringi` (though you'll get a matrix back)

```
library(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(df$V1, ' ', simplify = TRUE)
```